# understanding of spring bean scopes in a web application

Tags: java, spring, web, scope, javabeans

As per `springsource` documentation a `singleton` scoped bean is instantiated only once per
container. For example I have a singleton scoped `UserDetails` bean which contains information
about a user.
In my main() method:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"Spring-Customer.xml"});  
UserDetails ud1 = (UserDetails)context.getBean("userDetails");  
custA.setAddress("Address set by ud1");  
System.out.println("Address : " + ud1.getAddress());  

UserDetails ud2 = (UserDetails)context.getBean("userDetails");  
System.out.println("Address : " + ud2.getAddress());
```

The output will be

```
Address set by ud1  
Address set by ud1
```

Because of userDetails is a singleton bean, the second retrieval by `ud2` will give the same result as that of ud1.

**NOW** here is my problem:
For my web application I have the following `UserDetails` bean in my `dispatcher-servlet.xml.`

```
<bean id="userDetails" class="com.mukund.DTO.UserDetails" />
```

**first question:** is singleton scope is the default for a web application too ?
IF YES:
This bean is autowired into `AccountService` and `CustomerService` classes.
If a client say `clientA` has set the **first name** of the user to **"UserA"** in CustomerService class and after some time it retrieves the first name from AccountService class,

**second question:** does it get the **same** instance of UserDetails with "UserA" as the first name ?
**third question:** In the mean time if another client say `clientB` tries to get the first name in AccountService class will it get "UserA" ?
**fourth question:** will the same UserDetails instance be shared by clientA, clientB and others ? If yes: what scope to choose prototype, request or session.

*I hope you understand my point. Please explain me spring bean scopes with regards to a web application.*

THANKS

Answer (score 2):

Yes singleton is the default scope for web applications. So you get the same instance of UserDetails in all your services (and for all your users).

What scope is the right one for you depends on what you exactly want. Do you really want to inject a data transfer object into services? How long should the object exist?

- Prototype scope: Each service gets its own UserDetails object
- Request scope: You get same instance for the time of the request
- Session scope: You get the same instance as long as you are in the same session.

Comment: then what about the hibernate sessionfactory bean defined in dispatcher-servlet as `<bean id="sessionFactory" class="...">` ? Is it a singleton scoped bean if yes all users are going to use the same sessionfactory ? if yes then all will get the same session when `session.getCurrentSession` is called ? Please explain me this...

Comment: Yes the sessionfactory is a singleton. The SessionFactory is a heavy weight singleton style object while a session exists only for a "short" time span. The details and what `current session` means  is nicely explained in the hibernate documentation: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/context/CurrentSessionContext.html (just check the sub classes that matches your application). And please note that the standard spring way to create a SessionFactory is a http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html

Comment: Singleton scope is default for Spring, regardless the kind of application. Stateless beans should be marked as singleton or request, stateful beans can be prototype of session scoped, depending how long you want to use them.

Comment: Obviously values of a userdetails instance should not be shared between multiple users, so what scope would be appropriate for userdetails in a web-app?

Answer (score 1):

By Default the scope of spring beans is singleton that means one instance per container.
But that doesn't mean that the same instance is used by all requests.

It works like this.

Client A requests for bean A, the container will look for the instance of that bean A, if the instance is not available it will create an instance and then will give it to client A.

But if bean A is being used by another Client B then Client A has to wait till Client B releases  the bean A.

Comment: This is not right, you mean to say, that the singleton object is locked till it is use in a Client B, this can easily create a bottleneck for the application.

Comment: Thats true and that is why only the stateless beans are defined as spring beans.For example beans that easily qualify to be singleton are DAO,  Service ,  Controller these beans don’t have their own states instead we leverage these beans in our application to perform certain operations.Choosing a Singleton bean that needs to maintain it’s state is a bad design pattern